# Deleting spaces within words with regex - pre-processing data for text mining

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text, replace

For a school project I'm working on the kickstarter dataset on Kaggle;
https://www.kaggle.com/kemical/kickstarter-projects

In the "name" variable there's a few titles that have spaces in between them;
e.g. instance 373 **"C R O S S T O W N".**

I've been working on some regex all day to re.sub the extra spaces and try to get it to look as a normal word. Though I think this is a problem that occurs more often, most regex content is to add spaces, or add double-spaces. Never this specific task.

I've tried a couple of ways to describe the exact kind of space that needs te be deleted, single out the characters to keep as a group, and using them as the replace string. Though it looks like it should be working, my data doesn't change.

- long regex expression written to identify words that are written as spaces + single capitals (tried a couple of different ones for this)
- r'\2\4' refers to the second and fourth group (the first and second alphabetic character)

```html
Names_fixed = []
for i in Name_New: 
    Names_fixed.append(re.sub(r'(\s|^)([A-Z])(\s)(A-Z)\s/g', r'\2\4', i))
```

As I'm still pretty new to regex, turning to the community for help; thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(?<!\S)[A-Z](?:\s[A-Z])+(?!\S)', lambda x: re.sub(r'\s', '', x.group()), i)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizev, hero of the day, worked perfectly!!! Spent a whole day without cracking it, this is perfect!

Comment: Done! Thanks for the reminder guys, amazing this worked.

Comment: Thank you. Do not forget you can also upvote the answers you found helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```py
re.sub(r'(?<![ \t])[A-Z](?:[ \t][A-Z])+(?![ \t])', lambda x: x.group().replace(' ','').replace('\t',''), i)
```

Find space/tab-separated words and remove spaces/tabs from the found texts.

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ \t]                    any character of: ' ', '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ \t]                    any character of: ' ', '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ \t]                    any character of: ' ', '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ryszard, very clear description!

Answer (score 1):

If your target is only to remove spaces from words, am not sure if you really need regex.

You can use simple replace() function like this:

```
x = "C R O S S T O W N"
x = x.replace(' ','')
```

You can run a loop on your list for all such words.

Comment: Good one, though it would add the extra step of identifying and singling out those values.. gonna keep it in mind, thanks for your help :D

Comment: Very welcome. No you don't need to single out words, you can run this on all your words, this function will remove extra spaces if any, and leave the rest of the word as it is. Hope it helps :)